# how to write method with three parameters?

Tags: python

This function will receive three parameters. The first two are numbers and the third is a boolean value.
The function returns True if exactly one of the numbers is less than zero.  Unless the boolean parameter is True. In this case it will only return True if both numbers are less than zero.
If it doesn't return True, it returns False.

```
def pos_neg(a,b,negative):
    if a<0 or b<0 and negative=="false":
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: That's pretty fascinating. Do you have a question?

Comment: `if a<0 or b<0 and negative=="false"` ==> `if a<0 or b<0 and negative`

Comment: What's the issue? Also if you want *"exactly one of the numbers is less than zero"* you will want to use an XOR: `a<0 ^ b<0`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek note, that is technically the *bitwise* XOR, which will work differently than a boolean XOR (which doesn't actually exist in Python). It doesn't matter in this case because it is equivalent since you are using `bool` objects for both arguments, but perhaps worth noting

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I'm aware this is the bitwise XOR, but it's equivalent to a logical XOR for boolean comparisons which these are.

Answer (score 0):

> the third is a boolean value

`"false"` is a string. `False` is a boolean

> Unless the boolean parameter is True

So, why are you checking for false?

Anyway, you can just use boolean logic to use the boolean as-is.

Try this

```
def pos_neg(a,b,negative):
    a_neg = a < 0
    b_neg = b < 0
    if negative: 
        return a_neg and b_neg  # return True if both numbers are less than zero, otherwise False
    else:
        return a_neg ^ b_neg  # returns True if *exactly* one of the numbers is less than zero, otherwise False
```

Comment: thanks but it still get an error that says  Should return True because '
negative' is False and ints have opposite signs.")
AssertionError: False is not true : Should return True
 because 'negative' is False and ints have opposite signs.

Comment: @mandy Your stating the opposite in your question, so which is it? Go back and edit your question to clarify what you are wanting.

Comment: @mandy the question didn't say anything about "opposite signs", only negative values

Answer (score 0):

Returns True if exactly one of the numbers is less than zero, unless the Boolean parameter is True.
In this case [negative == True] it will only return True if both numbers are less than zero.
If it doesn't return True, it returns False.

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
    if not negative:
        if (a < 0) ^ (b < 0):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    else:
        if a < 0 and b < 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(pos_neg(-1, 1, False))  # True
print(pos_neg(-1, -1, False))  # False
print(pos_neg(-1, 1, True))  # False
print(pos_neg(-1, -1, True))  # True
```

will print:

```
True
False
False
True
```

Comment: `if cond: return True else: return False` is simply `return cond`

Comment: In other words, this seems to be the exact same logic as my answer

Comment: @cricket_007 Good point! I am just solving it line by line. It is more readable.

Comment: @cricket_007 It is not.

Comment: Why not? You're doing `return a < 0 and b < 0` when `if negative`

Comment: @cricket_007 You were missing operator precedence. After edit you did use redundant variables.

Comment: I have fixed my question to extract the `< 0` operation